# Hive Serde errors with Array<Struct<>> org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: arrays, json, struct, hive

I have created a table :

add jar /../xlibs/hive-json-serde-0.2.jar;

> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE SerdeTest
>   (Unique_ID  STRING
>   ,MemberID  STRING
>   ,Data ARRAY>
>   )
>
> PARTITIONED BY (Pyear INT, Pmonth INT)
>
> ROW FORMAT SERDE "org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.JsonSerde";
>
> ALTER TABLE SerdeTest ADD
>   PARTITION (Pyear = 2014, Pmonth =03) LOCATION  '../Test2';

The data in the file :

> {"Unique_ID":"ABC6800650654751","MemberID":"KHH966375835","Data":[{"SerialNo":1,"VariableName":"Var1","VariableValue":"A_49"},{"SerialNo":2,"VariableName":"Var2","VariableValue":"B_89"},{""SerialNo":3,"VariableName":"Var3","VariableValue":"A_99"}]}

Select query that I am using:

> select Data[0].SerialNo from SerdeTest where Unique_ID = 'ABC6800650654751';

however, when I run this query I get the following error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.objectinspector.StandardListObjectInspector.getList(StandardListObjectInspector.java:98)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:330)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:386)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:237)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:223)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:539)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:157)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:418)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:349)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1127)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)
>    ]

Can anyone please suggest me what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions: 
Make sure that all the packages of hive and hive-json-serde-0.2.jar have execute permission for hadoop user.
Hive creates a file called derby.log and metastore_db in the hive directory. It should be allowed to the user invoking the hive query to create files and directories.
Location for data should have / at the end. e.g. LOCATION '../Test2/';

Answer (score -1):

In short, **the working JAR** is json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar which can be found [here](http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3/cdh5/json-serde-1.3-jar-with-dependencies.jar). This one is working with 'STRUCT' and can even ignore some malformed JSON. During the creation of the table, include the following code:

```
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
 WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("ignore.malformed.json" = "true")
 LOCATION ...
```

If needed, it is possible to recompile it from [here](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde) or [here](https://github.com/sheetaldolas/Hive-JSON-Serde/tree/master). I tried the first repository and it is compiling fine for me, after adding the necessary libs. The repository has also been updated recently.

Check for more details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32785117/where-is-the-syntax-error-on-this-simple-hive-query-with-struct/32799551#32799551).

Comment: You are right, but I have few experience and actually I thought the other way around: it is a link to my own answer on the same site so if I update it, I won't need to update all the referenced answers also :) Nonetheless I will add more details here.

Comment: Thanks for updating it, that is more useful. :)